Asymptotic behavior of $(1-x)/(1-x+\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon\to 0$
Consider an integral
$$
I(\epsilon)=\int^{1}_{0} g(x,\epsilon)\cdot\frac{1-x}{1-x+\epsilon}dx
$$
with $g(x,\epsilon)$ a very complicated function.
Can I approximate this integral with
$$
I(\epsilon)\stackrel{?}{\approx}\int^{1}_{0} g(x,\epsilon)\cdot \frac{1-x}{1-x}dx =\int^{1}_{0} g(x,\epsilon)dx
$$
as $\epsilon\to 0$?
What puzzles me is that when $x\to 1$, the magnitude of $(1-x)$ can be comparable to $\epsilon$. Hence, the approximation
$$
\frac{1-x}{1-x+\epsilon}\approx \frac{1-x}{1-x} = 1
$$
might be problematic as $x\to 1$.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The integral is definite, so its result is not a function of $x$. Did you mean $I(\epsilon)$?

Thanks. Problem fixed.

Well what do you know about $g(x,\varepsilon)$? In particular do you know anything about the limit and or rate of that limit of $g(x,\varepsilon)\tfrac{\varepsilon}{1-x+\varepsilon}$ as $x\to 1$? Do you know that $g$ is bounded on $[0,1]$?

If $g$ is continuous and bounded, you can get such a result.

@EDX The function $g$ is continuous and bounded. I also added my concern in the post.

So $g$ is continuous and bounded.
That means :

$\forall x\in]0,1[, \  \epsilon \to g(x,\epsilon) $ is continuous
$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+, \  x \to g(x,\epsilon) $ is continuous
$\exists C>0, \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R} , \forall x\in]0,1[, \ |g(x,\epsilon)|<C $ (and the function $x \to C$ in integrable over $[0,1])$

Similarly :

$\forall x\in]0,1[, \  \epsilon \to g(x,\epsilon)\dfrac{1-x}{1-x+\epsilon} $ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^+$
$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+, \ f: x \to g(x,\epsilon)\dfrac{1-x}{1-x+\epsilon} $ is continuous on $[0,1]$ with  $f(1,0)=x\to g(1,0) $
$\exists C>0, \forall \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+ , \forall x\in]0,1[, \ |g(x,\epsilon)\dfrac{1-x}{1-x+\epsilon}|<C $ (and the function $x \to C$ in integrable over $[0,1])$ since $\dfrac{1-x}{1-x+\epsilon}$ is inferior to $1$.

Thus applying the continuity under the integral sign theorem :
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}I(\epsilon)=\int_0^1\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left(g(x,\epsilon)\dfrac{1-x}{1-x+\epsilon} \right)  dx=\int_0^1g(x,0)dx$$
